# Is there a word for urge toward clicking ad on a useful website/article?

Tags: single-word-requests

Whenever I browse through a website/blog and find an article/info useful then I click on one ad on site (I don't use ad blocker). I have this urge to give back and I think this is a "valid" way to give back for most of the blogs.

Sample Sentence > I pay back to a useful article by clicking an ad it contains.

Is there a word for this urge?

Comment: I'm pretty sure ***masochism*** is the best way to describe this. :P Joking aside, you could say you're ***paying it forward*** I guess. ***Reciprocating***? It's hard to think of a single word specifically describing the urge to give something back after receiving something good, but reciprocating as a verb for the act itself is the closest I've got.

Comment: The adjective would be "reciprocal" as in "I have a reciprocal urge to click ads on useful blog/website articles."

Comment: @JohnClifford you could post it as an answer :)

Comment: Please provide a sample sentence so we know what tense, sense, etc you have in mind.

Comment: Tarun: I posted as a comment because I wasn't sure this 100% gets across the meaning you were after.

Comment: @Lawrence I modified question

Comment: In social psychology, this is known as "the norm of ***[reciprocity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocity_(social_psychology))***".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try *acknowledge* in the following sense:

> **Acknowledge** *verb*
>   2.1 Express gratitude for or appreciation of: *he received a letter acknowledging his services*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/acknowledge)

Your sample sentence then becomes

> I *acknowledge* a useful article by clicking an ad it contains.

This expresses that when you consider an article to be useful, you express appreciation by helping them gain ad revenue by clicking on their ad.

If you're trying to more literally *pay* them, you can also try [*remunerate*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/remunerate), but that normally refers to more substantial payment for services rendered.